# Problemas con el DLL de Reportviewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer, dll

Cuando lleve mi trabajo en otra computadora la interfaz del reporte ya no funcionaba, todos los instaladores del reportviewer estan completos, pero aun asi nada.
Puse mi reportviewer en un Form .
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me sale este error, que no deja abrir el formulario, alguna solucion?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]